# How do I breed an Ice dragon?

Tags: dragonvale

How can I breed an Ice dragon?  I have tried, but haven't gotten the right dragon and keep getting the iceburg dragon.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this wiki page](http://dragonvale.wikia.com/wiki/Breeding) you've got a correct combination; which particular dragon you get from the pairing is decided randomly each time you breed them.

As long as the dragons you pair have at least one each of Cold and Water, you have a *chance* of getting the Ice dragon... In much the same way as rolling two dice gives you a *chance* to get 7. Just because you've rolled six times and gotten 8 4 5 9 9 5 doesn't mean that the dice are bad somehow.